# How to disable iTunes for one user

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes

I've searched both here and in all of the iTunes' preferences tabs. I wish there was a way to disable it from autostarting for one user.

I need to be sharing my wife's iMac for a while, but each time she connects her iPhone to charge, I get iTunes and iPhoto starting and wanting to import and sync.

How can I disable iTunes to autostart on one user account (but not others) on the latest OS X?

(Bonus question is how to do the same with iPhoto :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under System Preferences >  Users & Groups >  Login Items   Find iTunesHelper and remove it from the list of items that will open when you log in, this is the daemon that runs in the background checking for iOS devices connected.

If you want to disable it for only one device instead of one user, connect the device, open iTunes and uncheck "Automatically sync when device is connected".

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3927

For iPhoto I believe you can have another application open when connecting digital camera, not sure if it can be disabled.  Its a setting in iPhoto preferences, under General.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2500?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Thanks, that was it. When I log in next time, I'll be looking iPhoto up :)